# call custom controller in magento in java script

Tags: magento

I create a custom module named connector,company name is social.in that,there is a controller i.e. Social_Connectors_Customer_AccountController .in this controller ,action method is

```
public function connectAction()
{
    $this->_redirect('customer/account');
}
```

now,when i call this action method on click of my link,controller is somehow not called.and give me error like :The page you requested was not found, and we have a fine guess why.

java script in my phtml file is:how to call controller's action method in this script?

```
   document.observe('click', function(e){

      var target = e.findElement('a[rel^=google]') || e.findElement('button[rel^=google]');
      if (target && target.readAttribute('rel')=='google')
      {
      alert('<?php echo $this->getUrl(); ?>');
      }

      });
```

or can anybody say how to call controller on click of my link?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to call controller action,you must have to follow strucure of mvc magento module.and the function getUrl() must be define properly.check its defination.